# drag and drop one image over other image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, drag

I am trying to move one image(this image in tree view) into other image.
Using the following handler

```
 private void DragImage(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Image image = e.Source as Image;
        DataObject data = new DataObject(typeof(ImageSource), image.Source);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(image, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }

    private void DropImage(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ImageSource image = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ImageSource)) as ImageSource;
        Image imageControl = new Image() { Width = 50, Height = 30, Source = image };

        Canvas.SetLeft(imageControl, e.GetPosition(this.Canvas).X);
        Canvas.SetTop(imageControl, e.GetPosition(this.Canvas).Y);
        this.Canvas.Children.Add(imageControl);
    }
```

Once i drop the image over the canvas. It gets stick to it. I want to again move it on the same canvas.
Can you please suggest how it can be achieve??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this with some changes in the code.

```
 private void DragImage(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Image image = e.Source as Image;
        DataObject data = new DataObject(typeof(ImageSource), image.Source);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(image, data, DragDropEffects.All);
        moving = true;
    }


    private void DropImage(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        Image imageControl = new Image();
        if ((e.Data.GetData(typeof(ImageSource)) != null))
        {
            ImageSource image = e.Data.GetData(typeof(ImageSource)) as ImageSource;
            imageControl = new Image() { Width = 50, Height = 30, Source = image };
        }
        else
        {
            if ((e.Data.GetData(typeof(Image)) != null))
            {
                Image image = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Image)) as Image;
                imageControl = image;
                if (this.Canvas.Children.Contains(image))
                {
                    this.Canvas.Children.Remove(image);
                }
            }
        }

        Canvas.SetLeft(imageControl, e.GetPosition(this.Canvas).X);
        Canvas.SetTop(imageControl, e.GetPosition(this.Canvas).Y);
        imageControl.MouseLeftButtonDown += imageControl_MouseLeftButtonDown;
        this.Canvas.Children.Add(imageControl);

    }

    void imageControl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Image image = e.Source as Image;
        DataObject data = new DataObject(typeof(Image), image);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(image, data, DragDropEffects.All);
        moving = true;
    }
```